# After adding braces,file output not proper

Tags: c

I am not C programmer,I am just trying to get information from one code.So My modified code is here
http://pastebin.com/XYZXqzEW

The only difference is that I wanted to print index into f file.Firstly I have open file

```
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("new2.txt", "a");
```

and latter I have included braces around the fprintf

```
   if (xflg){
          index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
          fprintf(f,"%5d\n",index);
  } else {
      index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;
       vel[index] = velocity;
```

Original version was

```
 for (l=0; l<ny; l++)
            {
           if (xflg)
                  index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
           else
              index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;
               vel[index] = velocity;
/*               fprintf(stdout,"%.1f %.1f %.1f ", this_z, this_x, velocity); */
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

On line 221 is fwrite statement

```
yes = fwrite(vel, nxyz*sizeof(float), 1, f1_out);
```

When I compile and run the code,I got the base.mod(output file) with all zeros.Why?

Comment: Which base file?. Be more explicit. It's hard to answer your question with that little information.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. And don't just post external links!

Comment: ...and which braces did you add ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I have provided part of the code where i Have added braces in order to fprintf index to file.

Comment: @milenko sorry, I can't see which braces you are talking about. Edit ypour question and make that clear. Your question has 5 downvotes and 2 close requests. You should ask yourself why.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am sorry,I have edited question now.

Comment: There is no line `221` in the code shown. (Even if, we would not start counting lines)

Comment: @Olaf When I open pastebin link there is file with 231 line.

Comment: @milenko: Did you even read my first comment?? Please follow site-rules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
for (l=0; l<ny; l++)
{
  if (xflg)
    index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
  else
    index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;

  vel[index] = velocity;

  fprintf(f,"%5d\n",index);  //<<< line added

  /* fprintf(stdout,"%.1f %.1f %.1f ", this_z, this_x, velocity); */
}
```

or maybe this:

```
for (l=0; l<ny; l++)
{
  if (xflg)
  {                                   //<<< brace added
    index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
    fprintf(f,"%5d\n",index);         //<<< line added
  }                                   //<<< brace added
  else
    index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;

  vel[index] = velocity;
  /* fprintf(stdout,"%.1f %.1f %.1f ", this_z, this_x, velocity); */
}
```

I just added the `fprintf` line without any braces.

Your code is poorly indented, that's one of the reasons why you are having difficulties.

This is your original code, exactly the same as mine above but without the `fprintf(f,"%5d\n",index);`:

```
 for (l=0; l<ny; l++)
            {
           if (xflg)
                  index = m * nxy + l*nx + k;
           else
              index = m * nxy + k*ny + l;
               vel[index] = velocity;
/*               fprintf(stdout,"%.1f %.1f %.1f ", this_z, this_x, velocity); */
            }
```

I hope you understand now what I meant by "poor indentation" and why correct indentation is important.